# How to display download images in device gallery using ionic 3?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi i am new to ionic 3 and i developed an application and in that application i need to download and save images, videos, audio files into the device which are present in fireabse. i done with downloading the files and save into the device.  i am seeing the files saved in device with file manger  but when i open galley i am not seeing the downloaded files. how can i update or refresh the gallery to see the downloaded files in ionic 3.

sample code.

```
          path = this.file.externalDataDirectory;

          this.fileTransfer.download(payload.url,path+ name).then((entry) => {
                console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
                console.log(entry);

            }, (error) => {
                console.log("error while downloading the file");
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Please help me out to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

i try to user the photoLibrary but it is having issue with firebase URL.

sample code.

```
this.photoLibrary.saveImage("firebase url",
    "NoQ", {}).then(data => {
    alert("image saved successfully");
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("error starting downloading");
    console.log(error);
    this.requestPermission();
})
```